# Taylor Swift’s Style, similar song from the 80’s

Tags: similar-artists

While listening to [*Style*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-CmadmM5cOk) by Taylor Swift I can’t help but think that the initial guitar riff and the beat sound like a song from the 80’s but can’t recall which one.

Or... maybe it's just me being deceived either by a [clever algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pop_music_automation#Software) to create "original" music, or an artist making arrangements highly influenced by songs of that period. By the way the album is called 1989.

Comment: I have been racking my brain- I have had the same question for months now... Everytime style comes on I expect it to be another song- with a male lead singer but I don't know which one. I feel '80's era maybe around Miami Vice? I have listened to Peter Gabriel and that is not quite it. Any other options?

Comment: Her wildest dreams song sounds exactly like American money by Borns

Comment: Robyn - With Everyhearbeat the Intro same style

Comment: No its sounds like Chaka Khan - Ain't Nobody

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a subjective question, and obviously the song is deliberately intended as a general tribute to the sound of an earlier era (note the core lyric "we never go out of style"). But the song it most brings to mind for me is Peter Gabriel's "[In Your Eyes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B3kFPBtc9BE)" from the 1989 movie "Say Anything."  It's not a perfect match by any means, but there's a similar groove.

Lyrically speaking, there's a potential callback to the 1989 hit "[Rock On](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K2v-DMpgO7o)," but there's not as much of a auditory resemblance there.

Answer (score 3):

When I heard it, I had a similar reaction (though, it goes in a slightly different direction) The Who Eminence Front
https://youtu.be/5HTVMh7fur4?t=3m45s

Answer (score 1):

Depeche Mode songs [*It's no good*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aieEZ950d1I) or [*Precious*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=auDmlbaH590) have the same kind of arrangement at the beginning of the song.

Answer (score 0):

When I hear Style by Taylor Swift I think of this group and song. The Ataris - Boys Of Summer

Comment: could you add link to the song?

Comment: Can you explain how this two songs are similar?